# Simple shopping cart in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to learning the basics of JavaScript and i was practicing it by making a simple "shopping cart".  Its one of my first works I did on JavaScript.

This is what needs to happen:

You need to select an option from the dropdown menu and give in a number (how much you want) in the "input field". That you submit with the button and it needs to show up in the table below with the following information: Name of the product, how much you want, and a subprice. I all got that working.

But these are my problems:

- First problem: When I select the same product and add it, it adds a new row in the table, and thats not what I want. I needs to count up with the same product you already orderd.
- Second problem: I don't know how to sum all the subtotals up to get a total price of all products. It needs to change on the go in the html document when you submit a product.

This is my code:

```js
"use strict";

//Lijst met info van groeten.
const allGroenten = [
{ naam: "Bloemkool", prijs: 1.15, eenheid: "stuk" },
{ naam: "Chinese kool", prijs: 1.95, eenheid: "stuk" },
{ naam: "Wortelen", prijs: 0.99, eenheid: "kg" }
];


//DROPDOWN MENU INVULLEN MET DE OBJECTEN VAN ALLGROENTEN

const select = document.getElementById("groenten"); 
for (let i = 0; i < allGroenten.length; i++) {
    const opt = allGroenten[i].naam;
    const el = document.createElement("option");
    el.text = opt + "  -  " + "\u20AC" + allGroenten[i].prijs + " /" + allGroenten[i].eenheid;
    el.value = allGroenten[i].prijs;
    el.dataset.naam = allGroenten[i].naam;
    el.id = [i]
    select.add(el);
}

// EVENT .onClick op Toevoeg button
document.getElementById("toevoegen").onclick = function() {

    invoerAub.innerText = "";
    let aantalCheck = document.getElementById("aantal");
    let check = aantalCheck.value;

    selecteerAub.innerText = "";
    let selecteerCheck = document.getElementById("groenten");
    let checkSelect = selecteerCheck.value;
    
    if (check == false) {

        const invoerAub = document.getElementById("invoerAub");
        invoerAub.innerText = "Aantal ingeven aub.";

    } else if (checkSelect == false) {
        
        const invoerAub = document.getElementById("selecteerAub");
        invoerAub.innerText = "Selecteer u groeten aub.";
        
    } else {

        const tbody = document.querySelector("tbody");
        const tr = tbody.insertRow();
        
        const naamTd = tr.insertCell();
        const naamInput = document.getElementById("groenten");
        naamTd.innerText = naamInput.options[naamInput.selectedIndex].text;
        
        const aantalTd = tr.insertCell();
        const aantalInput = document.getElementById("aantal");
        aantalTd.innerText = aantalInput.value;
        
        const subtotaalTd = tr.insertCell();
        subtotaalTd.dataset.subPrijs = aantalInput.value * naamInput.value;
        let subtotaalInput = aantalInput.value * naamInput.value;
        subtotaalTd.innerText = subtotaalInput.toFixed(2);

        

        // naamInput.value = "";
        // aantalInput.value = "";
        // subtotaalInput = "";
    }
};
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="nl">
    <head>
        <script src="javascript-test-2.js" defer></script>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="javascript.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css">    
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div id="container">
            
              <!-- BESTEL FORMULIER -->

              <h2>Bestelformulier</h2>

                  <label for="groenten">Kies u groenten</label>
                  <!-- <span id="selecteerAub" style="color: red;"></span> -->
                  <span id="selecteerAub" class="fout">Verplicht te kiezen.</span>
                  <select name="groenten" id="groenten" class="required">
                      <option id="defaultOption" value="" disabled selected hidden>Kies hier...</option>
                  </select>
                  <span id="kiesGroente"></span>


                  </br>

                <!-- <span id="invoerAub" style="color: red;"></span> -->
                <span id="invoerAub" class="fout">Verplicht een getal in te voeren.</span>
                  <label>Aantal</label>
                  <input id="aantal" type="number" min="1" required/>
                  <button type="submit" id="toevoegen">Toevoegen in mijn mandje</button>
                  </br>
                  
              <!-- Shopping cart -->

              <div id="winkelmandje">
                <h2>Winkelmandje</h2>

                <div>

                    <p>Totaal:</p><span id="totaalBerekenen"></span>

                </div>

              </div>
              <table id="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Naam</th>
                    <th>Aantal</th>
                    <th>Subtotaal</th>
                </tr>
                <!-- JS will insert here new TR -->
              </table>

            </div>
          </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: When you add an item to the cart, you need to loop through all existing items in that cart to see if any of them match up with what you're trying to add. If so, just update the quantity of the existing item, otherwise add the new item.

Second problem. When you add or update an item in the table (the cart I'm guessing), recalculate the totals.

Comment: @Phaelaxz So i  loop over like i do a loop on the data for the select? I thought about that, i but i don't know how to make it like that. Also, how do i "update" the quantity of the existing item?

And for my second problem. I also don't know how to do that. I tried to put them into an array, but i didn't work. Because i need to fix problem number one first ( i guess).

Comment: A DO loop would be unfitting for this case, you'd want to look at a FOR loop.  I had to move the javascript to the end of the document, otherwise it was trying to create the SELECT options before the element even existed because the document was not ready yet.

Comment: There are a lot better ways to do all this, but I can see you're very new so I'll just stick with what you got for now.   Grab the tbody element and loop over all the rows (TR) elements.  Do this before you add a new row. Look at the column in the table that contains the name of the item. If the name matches what the user is trying to add, then update the values on these elements rather than add a new row.  

You used FOR loops before, when you created your SELECT element.

Comment: @Phaelaxz Yea, im very new to this. I started like a week or 2 with javascript. :D Can you tell? Haha!
Witch part of the javascript did you move to the end? You mean the script tag in the html file? And what is a DO loop? I never seen that before. 

Ok, i can try that. And how do i update an exciting value in my html file? Do i delete the previous one and make an new one?

Already big thanks man!

Comment: @Phaelaxz Btw, can you make an example of how you would do it? If its not to much work for you mate!

Comment: Here is hint towards a solution. Right now, you are simply adding new table rows with each submit, but you don't have any data structure for storing submissions. What JavaScript data structure could you use here? (Probably an object literal or even a Set). So begin by initializing an empty object. On each submission, check if a key exists for the item type, if not create one, otherwise update the quantity for each key. And then create a function that will be able to generate your table from this object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Comment: I moved the entire script to the end of the file just for simplicity. And nevermind about the DO loop, I misread what you wrote. You stare at so many languages for too long you start to mix things up.

Comment: @wlh Thanks for the comment. I appreciate it alot! Ok, i get what you mean. I tried that before, but i tried to store the data in a object literal after i added it to my table and i did it in my functies. ( What it did was reset my first value of my array of objects. I think because its loops over it with that function? )
So i have to start all over? Begin from scratch? :D

Answer (score 1):

To solve your two questions you need to decide on a datatype for persisting the quantity and subtotal. There are many ways to do this.

Below, I simply added a `quantity` and `subtotal` key to each of the objects within the `allGroenten` array. You can rename these later.

Then, when someone submits your simple form, instead of adding a success of rows to the table, we are going to regenerate the entire `tbody` from the data source each time. To better facilitate this, I added and empty `tbody` to the html as well as moved the `tr` full of your headers into a `thead` element.

Then each time someone clicks the button, based on valid data, we grab the name and value and update only the quantity and subtotal for the relevant object. And while we are iterating through the array, we are rebuilding the table with updated data and finally we are updating the total.

See below with added comments:

```js
"use strict";

//Lijst met info van groeten. but add quantity and subtotal to persist data
const allGroenten = [
  { naam: "Bloemkool", prijs: 1.15, eenheid: "stuk", quantity: 0, subtotal: 0.0 },
  { naam: "Chinese kool", prijs: 1.95, eenheid: "stuk", quantity: 0, subtotal: 0.0 },
  { naam: "Wortelen", prijs: 0.99, eenheid: "kg", quantity: 0, subtotal: 0.0 }
];

// store currency to reuse
const currency = "\u20AC";

//DROPDOWN MENU INVULLEN MET DE OBJECTEN VAN ALLGROENTEN
const select = document.getElementById("groenten"); 
for (let i = 0; i < allGroenten.length; i++) {
    const opt = allGroenten[i].naam;
    const el = document.createElement("option");
    el.text = opt + "  -  " + currency + allGroenten[i].prijs + " /" + allGroenten[i].eenheid;
    el.value = allGroenten[i].prijs;
    el.dataset.naam = allGroenten[i].naam;
    el.id = [i]
    select.add(el);
}

// EVENT .onClick op Toevoeg button
document.getElementById("toevoegen").onclick = function() {

    invoerAub.innerText = "";
    let aantalCheck = document.getElementById("aantal");
    let check = aantalCheck.value;

    selecteerAub.innerText = "";
    let selecteerCheck = document.getElementById("groenten");
    let checkSelect = selecteerCheck.value;
    
    if (check == false) {

        const invoerAub = document.getElementById("invoerAub");
        invoerAub.innerText = "Aantal ingeven aub.";

    } else if (checkSelect == false) {
        
        const invoerAub = document.getElementById("selecteerAub");
        invoerAub.innerText = "Selecteer u groeten aub.";
        
    } else {
        const naamInput = document.getElementById("groenten");
        const naam = naamInput.options[naamInput.selectedIndex].text;

        const aantalInput = document.getElementById("aantal");
        const addQuantity = aantalInput.value;
        
        // reset the tbody on each transaction
        const tbody = document.querySelector("tbody");
        tbody.innerHTML = '';
  
        // initialize totaal sum variable
        let totaal = 0.0;
        
        // updated quantity && subtotal and update DOM
        for (let i = 0; i < allGroenten.length; i++) {
        
            // update quantity and subtotal based on input
            if (naam.includes(allGroenten[i].naam)) {
                // ensure data type stays as Number
                allGroenten[i].quantity = +allGroenten[i].quantity + +addQuantity
                allGroenten[i].subtotal = allGroenten[i].quantity * allGroenten[i].prijs
            }
            
            // update subtotal and total for all

            const tr = tbody.insertRow();
            const naamTd = tr.insertCell();
            naamTd.innerText = allGroenten[i].naam;
            
            const aantalTd = tr.insertCell();
            aantalTd.innerText = allGroenten[i].quantity;
        
            const subtotaalTd = tr.insertCell();
            subtotaalTd.dataset.subPrijs = allGroenten[i].subtotal;
            subtotaalTd.innerText = allGroenten[i].subtotal.toFixed(2);
            
            totaal += allGroenten[i].subtotal
 
        }
        // show total
        const totaalBerekenen = document.getElementById("totaalBerekenen");
        totaalBerekenen.innerText = currency + totaal.toFixed(2)


    }
};
```

```html
<div id="container">
<!-- BESTEL FORMULIER -->
  <h2>Bestelformulier</h2>
  <label for="groenten">Kies u groenten</label>
  <!-- <span id="selecteerAub" style="color: red;"></span> -->
  <span id="selecteerAub" class="fout">Verplicht te kiezen.</span>
  <select name="groenten" id="groenten" class="required">
    <option id="defaultOption" value="" disabled selected hidden>Kies hier...</option>
  </select>
  <span id="kiesGroente"></span>
  <br/>
  <!-- <span id="invoerAub" style="color: red;"></span> -->
  <span id="invoerAub" class="fout">Verplicht een getal in te voeren.</span>
  <label>Aantal</label>
  <input id="aantal" type="number" min="1" required/>
  <button type="submit" id="toevoegen">Toevoegen in mijn mandje</button>
  <br/>
             
  <!-- Shopping cart -->
  <div id="winkelmandje">
    <h2>Winkelmandje</h2>
  <div>
    <p>Totaal:</p><span id="totaalBerekenen"></span>
  </div>
  <br/>
 
   <table id="table">
     <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>Naam</th>
        <th>Aantal</th>
        <th>Subtotaal</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <!-- JS will insert here new TR -->
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh yea, i see what you did there. Now i understand. Its almost like i wanted to. You let all the products come in once in the table at the same time. So you select one, and all the products are in the table after submitting. What i wanted to do was select one product and and it on by one. If you know what i mean?

Comment: @Dny You can change this to only add the products that have a quantity if you like. But this gives you something to work from.